# How to show Dropdownlist on page load in Jqxgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I'm using Jqxgrid of jqwidgets.

I have taken a dropdown list in a grid.

I want to show dropdown list in editable mode by default on page load.

please have a look this screen shot where first dropdown showing as 'Please Choose' , it's coming on click on grid cell , how to bind it default.

[image]

Below is the code.

```
{
                text: 'Position of meter in Rack', datafield: 'MeterPositionInRack', width: 180, columntype: 'dropdownlist', editable: true,
                createeditor: function (row, column, editor) {
                    var list = ['1', '2', '3' ,'4'];
                    editor.jqxDropDownList({ autoDropDownHeight: true, source: list, selectedIndex: 0 });

                    editor.jqxDropDownList.bind('select', function (event) {
                        var args = event.args;
                        var item = $('#jqxdropdownlist').jqxDropDownList('getItem', args.index);
                        alert('Selected: ' + item.label);
                    });
                }
                , initeditor: function (row, cellvalue, editor) {
                    var list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
                    console.log("initeditor: " + list1);
                    editor.jqxDropDownList({ autoDropDownHeight: true, source: list1, selectedIndex: 0 });
                }
            }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jqxgrid has `ready` properties to do anything after the grid is initialized and the binding is complete, so you can trigger begin update method:

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
 ...
 ready: function () {
          $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('beginrowedit', 0);
      },
 ...
 });
```

**See also**:

- [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/e3m2L11t/)
- [Jqxgrid ready properties](http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/Xr4LS/)

Comment: Thanks Rong for reply, It's working for single row , How can I applied for all rows, please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/e3m2L11t/6/

Comment: aah.. Thank you Rong its fine...:)